# React Router Dom - React Router changing url but not page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a simple routing system with react, but when i click on a link to navigate to another page it just changes the URL but not showing the content, then when i press F5 it shows anything fine.

Here's my code, i can't understand what i'm doing wrong, i tried also to create another app but the result is the same.

**Index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Notes from "./pages/Notes/Notes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
        <Route path="/notes" component={Notes} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard**

```
import PageContent from "../../components/PageContent/PageContent";
import ResponsiveDrawer from "../../components/ResponsiveDrawer/ResponsiveDrawer";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ResponsiveDrawer>
        <PageContent
          header={
            <div className={`flex-row`}>
              <h1
                className={`font-extrabold tracking-tight truncate capitalize`}
              >
                dashboard
              </h1>
            </div>
          }
          body={<>Bentornato utente!</>}
        ></PageContent>
      </ResponsiveDrawer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: What version of RR are you using? There were some significant changes made between 5 and 6.

Comment: So i tried before using the 5.2.0 copying for an older project. Then i tried switching to the last 6 but the result is the same.

Comment: This is a known issue with `react-router-dom@5` and the `react@18` `StrictMode` component. See linked duplicate for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using version 6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6).

1. Import `Routes` instead of `Switch` and replace `<Switch>` in your code.
2. Use `element` instead of component, and add the actual component as its value rather than just the name.
3. You should probably move the `Notes` route first as I think the ordering has an effect.

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/notes" element={<Notes />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} exact />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: That's it! The problem was that i was uninstalling the 5.2.0 version and just giving:
npm install react-router-dom, but this was actually not installing the 6th version. So i typed react-router-dom@6 and now it's working.